# Get X, Y position of value on UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, position, uislider

I am trying to get the X,Y position of a particular value on a UISlider track so I can place a textfield at that location before I even move the slider with my thumb. I want to be able to place multiple textfields along the track showing what value is at that location.

Could anybody help me achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: you will get value by `sliderObject.value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let values: [Float] = [15, 30, 50, 70, 85]

for value in values {
    guard (slider.minimumValue...slider.maximumValue).contains(value) else { continue }

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "\(value)"

    view.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let thumbRect = slider.thumbRect(forBounds: slider.bounds,
                                     trackRect: slider.trackRect(forBounds: slider.bounds),
                                     value: value)

    let convertedThumbRect = slider.convert(thumbRect, to: view)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: convertedThumbRect.midX),
        slider.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(label.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1)
    ])
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help... :)

Answer (score 3):

For this first you find frame of the thumb image of UISlide.

For find frame of the thumb image of UISlide use this method:-

```
@IBAction func sliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let _thumbRect: CGRect = sender.thumbRect(forBounds: sender.bounds, trackRect: sender.trackRect(forBounds: sender.bounds), value: sender.value)

        let thumbRect: CGRect = view.convert(_thumbRect, from: sender)

        print("thumbRect \(thumbRect)")


    }
```